# char配列をstringに変換できない

Tags: c#

C#でN 個の 2 進数のデータに対して排他的論理和(xor) を取った結果を 4 桁の 2 進数で出力
するプログラムを作っています。
その際、char配列をstringに変換する機能を実装中に以下の問題が発生しました。
以下の「作成したソースコード」の、

```
string output = new string(finalCharAnsArray);
int intOutput = int.Parse(output);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0000}", intOutput));
```

の部分の、

```
string output = new string(finalCharAnsArray);
```

の部分で、
char配列をstringに変換できなくて困っています。
（outputの中身が"\u0001\0\u0001"になっています。本当は"101"の文字列にしたいです。）

<作成したソースコード>

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace CsharpPractice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int inputCount = 2;
            int[] inputs = new int[inputCount];
            inputs[0] = 0011;
            inputs[1] = 0110;
            int answer = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < inputCount; i++)
            {
                answer += inputs[i];  
            }
            string strAns = answer.ToString();
            char[] charAnsArray = strAns.ToCharArray();
            int[] finalAns = new int[charAnsArray.Length];
            char[] finalCharAnsArray = new char[charAnsArray.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < finalAns.Length; i++)
            {
                finalAns[i] = (int)charAnsArray[i];
                finalAns[i] %= 2;
                finalCharAnsArray[i] = (char)finalAns[i];
            }
            string output = new string(finalCharAnsArray);
            int intOutput = int.Parse(output);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0000}", intOutput));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

OSはWindows10, 
エディターはVisual Studio2015を使用しています。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/169863

Answer (score 5, accepted):

質問タイトルは「char配列をstringに変換できない」ですが、そもそも入力データが何もかも間違っていて、変換の前提条件が整っていません。

> ```
> inputs[0] = 0011;
> ```

「2 進数のデータ」とありますが、このコードは10進数のデータです。Visual Studio 2017およびC# 7.0以降であれば[バイナリリテラル](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#numeric-literal-syntax-improvements)を用いて `0b0011` とでき、2進数のデータを直接表現できます（10進数の`3`になります）。

> ```
> answer += inputs[i];
> ```

「排他的論理和(xor)」とありますが、[`+`は加算](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator)です。[排他的論理和(xor)`^`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator)を使う必要があります。

---

現状の`inputs`を元に解を得るには全く異なるアプローチをとる必要があります。[`Convert.ToInt32()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_System_Int32_)および[`Convert.ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int32_System_Int32_)では１０進数文字列や２進数文字列を扱えるため、これを用いて基数変換できます。
また、[`Select()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__)や[`Aggrigate()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___0___0__)を使用するとループを分かりやすく表現できます。

```
var inputs = new []{ 0011, 0110 };
var result = inputs
    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString(), 2))
    .Aggrigate((x, y) => x ^ y);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(result, 2));
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。